If I distribute GPLv2-licensed software as a bundle that uses a virtual machine to run it, do I need to open-source the virtual machine too?
This is the Setup that will be distributed already packaged together:

An MIT licensed Virtual Machine with some modified code
A GPL-2.0 software binary with some modified code

I understand that the source code with the modifications of the software binary need to be provided to recipients of the distributed package under GPL-2.0, but what about the modifications to the Virtual Machine that runs this binary?

Section 2 of GPLv2 states:

In addition, mere aggregation of another work not based on the Program
with the Program (or with a work based on the Program) on a volume of
a storage or distribution medium does not bring the other work under
the scope of this License.

I would consider distribution of the virtual machine together with the GPLv2 software as falling under the above clause on aggregation on a distribution medium. Hence, the GPLv2 does not apply to the virtual machine.
In any case, the virtual machine can run with or without the GPLv2 software as it is not linked with it. And the GPLv2 software too can run outside a virtual machine. So, it pretty much is a case of aggregation, from a functional perspective.
Also, the bolded statement in GPL FAQ quote below explains that the use of containers (and by extension, virtual machines) does not affect the analysis of aggregation.

What is the difference between an “aggregate” and other kinds of
“modified versions”? (#MereAggregation)
An “aggregate” consists of a number of separate programs, distributed
together on the same CD-ROM or other media. The GPL permits you to
create and distribute an aggregate, even when the licenses of the
other software are nonfree or GPL-incompatible. The only condition is
that you cannot release the aggregate under a license that prohibits
users from exercising rights that each program's individual license
would grant them.
Where's the line between two separate programs, and one program with
two parts? This is a legal question, which ultimately judges will
decide. We believe that a proper criterion depends both on the
mechanism of communication (exec, pipes, rpc, function calls within a
shared address space, etc.) and the semantics of the communication
(what kinds of information are interchanged).
If the modules are included in the same executable file, they are
definitely combined in one program. If modules are designed to run
linked together in a shared address space, that almost surely means
combining them into one program.
By contrast, pipes, sockets and command-line arguments are
communication mechanisms normally used between two separate programs.
So when they are used for communication, the modules normally are
separate programs. But if the semantics of the communication are
intimate enough, exchanging complex internal data structures, that too
could be a basis to consider the two parts as combined into a larger
program.
When it comes to determining whether two pieces of software form a
single work, does the fact that the code is in one or more containers
have any effect? (#AggregateContainers)
No, the analysis of whether they are a single work or an aggregate is
unchanged by the involvement of containers.


Depends.

If your virtual machine changes do not affect 4 essential freedoms of the user of the GPL program, then you need to distribute only sources+changes for that GPL app, and not for MIT VM.

That would happen for example if your VM changes were performance improvements, extra features not required by the app etc.
This is the usual case, unless people are intentionally trying to circumvent copyleft spirit.

However, if your virtual machines changes are tailored in such a way that do not allow the user of the GPL to exercise their freedoms (for example add their own modifications and run that instead), than that can change and require VM code and changes to be supplied too.
there are two basic groups of situations where that can happen:

you disable the user from modifying the GPL code in VM, e.g. you not provide "all the source code for all modules it contains, plus any associated interface definition files, plus the scripts used to
control compilation and installation of the executable" as required by GPL-2 section 3., or
if functionality needed for GPL program to function properly are inside your MIT VM changes and GPL program is linked to that VM (now non-free) libraries, i.e. it makes VM derived work of GPL app (e.g. usual attempted abuse case: company only modifies the GPL code to call external libraries and distribute those changes, and libraries are non-free)



